# How to align a prooftree left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bussproofs

How to align a bussproofs prooftree left?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}    
\begin{prooftree}
    \LeftLabel{(Proof)}
    \AxiomC{A}
    \AxiomC{B}
    \BinaryInfC{C}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

I tried putting it in an array and a table but the compilation did not run through

Comment: Have you tried putting the `prooftree` inside a `minipage`?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Yes, but then I have to align the tree within the minipage or manually make the minipage the exact size of the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it mandatory for you to use the `prooftree`environment? In addition to that environment, the `bussproofs`package also offers to have “in-line” proofs. To quote from the manual (p.3):

> The `\DisplayProof` command allows you to put proofs anywhere normal
>   text might appear; for example, in a paragraph, in a table, in a
>   tabbing environment, etc.

Hence, omitting the `rooftree` wrapper and use `\DisplayProof` at the end of the proof let you put the proof anywhere. Per default, this should then amount to being left-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}    
    \LeftLabel{(Proof)}
    \AxiomC{A}
    \AxiomC{B}
    \BinaryInfC{C}
    \DisplayProof
\end{document}
```

Using the `\EnableBpAbbreviations`command, you can also abbreviate the `\DisplayProof`(and many other) commands, so that your proof can be produced by the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\EnableBpAbbreviations
\begin{document}    
    \LeftLabel{(Proof)}
    \AXC{A}
    \AXC{B}
    \BIC{C}
    \DP
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using \DisplayProof I am now also able to put a proof in a table

Answer (score 1):

The `prooftree` environment centers the display; use `\DisplayProof`. The frames are just to show the placement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\noindent\mbox{%
  \LeftLabel{(Proof)}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \BinaryInfC{C}
  \DisplayProof
}

\end{document}
```

[image]